# Symfony add multiple arguments to extensions to get current logged in user

Tags: php, symfony

I need to call doctrine and logged in user in symfony extensions.

this is my service yml

```
twig.extension.app:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
    arguments:
        $doctrine : '@doctrine'
        $context  : '@security.context'
    tags:
      -  { name: twig.extension }


twig.extension.auth:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\AuthExtension
    arguments:
        $doctrine : '@doctrine'
        $context  : '@security.context'
    tags:
      -  { name: twig.extension }
```

in my case, i devide it to be two extensions.

and this is my extensions :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class AuthExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $doctrine;
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine, Security $context)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->context = $context;
    }
}
```

but I got error :

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\AutowiringFailedException]                                                                                                                         
  Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension": argument "$context" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security" but no such service exists. It cannot be auto-registered because it is from a different root namespace.
```

how to solve this, in condition i need doctrine and also current logged in user?

Comment: Never saw security.context before, used to using security.token_storage for logged in user.  Are you using the full framework with the security bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Twig Extension, you should add to it into `services.yml`. This is a sample;

```
twig.json_decode:
    class: DashboardBundle\Twig\Extension\JsonDecode
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

If you need another object, you should send to objects;

```
twig.json_decode:
    class: DashboardBundle\Twig\Extension\JsonDecode
    arguments: [ "@doctrine_object_name", "@security_object_name" ]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Another way, you can send `service_container`object.